# SQL query to return column that is associated to another column with a certain value

Tags: sql, oracle

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10068 | CP |
| 10068 | DF |
| 10068 | DP |
| 10069 | CP |
| 10061 | CP |

I have this table and I am trying to write a SQL query in Oracle, such that it fetches col1s that have corresponding col2 as 'CP' only and nothing else. In above example, data returned should be 10069 and 10061, it should not return 10068 as it has DF and DP as well associated.

Below is my query but it doesn't work, it is fetching col1 with 10068 as well

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2 
FROM SAMPLETABLE 
WHERE COL2 NOT IN ('DF', 'DP')
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select col1
from sampletable t
group by col1
having min(col2) = max(col2) and min(col2) = 'CP'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`

```
 create table SAMPLETABLE ( COL1 int, COL2 varchar(10));


 insert into SAMPLETABLE values(10068,  'CP');
 insert into SAMPLETABLE values(10068,  'DF');
 insert into SAMPLETABLE values(10068,  'DP');
 insert into SAMPLETABLE values(10069,  'CP');
 insert into SAMPLETABLE values(10061,  'CP');
```

Query:

```
 select col1,col2 from sampletable a
 where not exists
                 (select 1 from sampletable b where a.col1=b.col1 and b.col2<'CP')
```

Output:

| COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 10061 | CP |
| 10069 | CP |

Or you can also use group by with having clause:

Query:

```
select col1  from SAMPLETABLE 
 group by col1
 having count(distinct col2)=1
 and min(col2) ='CP'
```

Output:

| COL1 |
| --- |
| 10061 |
| 10069 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c30e226b0ecce068f27ad497ba46256c)*

Comment: Actual values in col2 are AF, AP,DP and CP. As up above <'CP' wouldnt work I guess, since I have AF as well

Comment: It will work I think even if you have AF. Since I have also checked ount(distinct col2)=1.